# Free software license allowing re-distribution but disallowing editing/reverse engineering

Tags: licensing

Which software license should one use to meet the following simple conditions:

1. Software is free to use
2. Software can be re-distributed
3. Software source is closed and remains my intellectual property
   (copywright) and cannot be decompiled/edited.
4. (If possible) The software cannot be sold.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general you cannot forbid reverse engineering, because it commonly falls under fair use under many legislations.

Comment: By definition there is no "free software license" that does what you want. Hire a lawyer to write a license for you.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of free software is that it can be modified to suit any user's potential requirements, so pretty much by definition, if you want point 3, your software isn't free.

Comment: You are enforcing a definition of "free" which is not the only possible definition.  "Free to use" sounds pretty free to me (free as in no cost), although it is certainly not FLOSS (free as in liberty).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like shareware.  I can't point you to a license I would personally recommend, but Google has lots of results.  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shareware